# Icon alignment is bad when zoom chrome to 125 or other scale?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have following code from one template:

My code is upload on:

[JSFIDDLe](https://jsfiddle.net/9g372oys/)

```
<div class="sidebar-body" dir="rtl">
        <div class="side-logo d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
       </div>
</div>

 <div class="side-contact">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="la la-map-marker"></i>22222</li>
                        <li><i class="la la-phone"></i>+3333</li>
                        <li><i class="la la-envelope"></i>asdasdasd</li>
                    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .main-menu .sidebar-body .side-contact {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.main-menu .sidebar-body .side-contact ul li {
    color: #666666;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-menu .sidebar-body .side-contact ul li i {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #05ab90;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
}
```

[image]

in 100%, 200% and ... all things is okey but when Zoom in chrome to 125 (for example) one last icon alignment gets into trouble and not align with other icons.

[image]

attach a live link on jsfiddle

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D  I try to upload thanks

Comment: @LaljiTadhani icon is put on line-awesome.min.css file how I can attach it via fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `clear: both` on each line item element. The problem is the two `float: left` icons are bumping into each other. Adding the `clear` to each row will ensure that a new block is started since floated elements are pulled out of the flow of content.

```
.main-menu .sidebar-body .side-contact ul li {
    color: #666666;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it needs to be applied to the `li i` icon element instead. I might be mistaken. If not, I'll remove my answer. Usually that's what I have to do to fix that problem.

Comment: this problem is just occurred on chrome !!